# If I develop an HTML game or an application for a Windows pc, will it work on a Windows Phone?

Tags: apps

I am developing an HTML5 application for Windows 8 desktop using JavaScript and [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). Can I use the same application on PC, phones and tablets?

Comment: Sorry but it is a developer question. It will fit better on Stackoverflow.